# Java passing array error

Tags: java, arrays, object

I've looked around and I can't see why I'm having this problem. Basically, I'm passing an array of player objects but after passing them I can't access the details correctly.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2;i++){
    players[i] = new Player(names[i], chipCount);
    System.out.println(players[i].getName());
    }
```

This for loop is in my main method. I have another for loop that sets up three players (Player is an object that requires a name and a number of chips, and has two methods - `getName()` and `getChips()`). The players are "Bob" "Billy" and "Barney" and in the above loop they get printed out fine, however when I pass the array of players over to my 'Game' class, attempting to print the player's names in the same way as above just prints "Barney Barney Barney" instead.

Code for Game class:

```
public class Game {

Player[] players;
int pot = 0;

public Game(Player[] player){
    this.players = player;
}

public void startGame(int rounds){

    int roundNumber = 1;

    while(roundNumber != rounds){
        System.out.println("Starting round " + roundNumber);
        System.out.print("Players: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
                System.out.print(players[i].getName() + " ");
                }   
        System.out.println("");
        roundNumber = rounds;
    }
}
```

}

And how I'm calling Game:

```
Game game = new Game(players);
```

Anyone know why it's not printing out the names correctly? Am I passing the array incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you instantiate `players` array in `Game game = new Game(players);`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that the fields (`name` and `chips`) in `Player` are `static`. They shouldn't.

Read the [Java tutorial about instance and static members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: @user2171122 Don't forget to accept this answer if it has helped you